# MVC 2.0 C# ModelUpdate wont update

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having trouble getting a ModelUpdate or TryModelUpdate to work in my code.

I'm using the default Role Manager and Login system created by MVC when running the ASP.Net configuration tool.  What I'm trying to do is add another column to the Users table so I can record if my users are also customers.  So I want to record their CustomerID there.

I used the ADO Entity Data Model to generate all my model code based off my database.  The code it created for the field I want to update is here:

```
    public string CustomerID
    {
        get
        {
            return this._CustomerID;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OnCustomerIDChanging(value);
            this.ReportPropertyChanging("CustomerID");
            this._CustomerID = global::System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true);
            this.ReportPropertyChanged("CustomerID");
            this.OnCustomerIDChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _CustomerID;
    partial void OnCustomerIDChanging(string value);
    partial void OnCustomerIDChanged();
```

In my controller Im trying to update the CustomerID field with this code:

```
                var userToUpdate = dbu.aspnet_Users.First(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
                UpdateModel(userToUpdate, new string[] { "CustomerID"}, txtID);
                dbu.SaveChanges();
```

But I get an error saying the overload method has some invalid arguments.

I get that the issue is in assigning txtID to CustomerID based off the error, but whats the correct way to do it?

If I need to add more info please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparantly ModelUpdate won't let me pass in custom data and it needs to be passed in from the Form Collection.  So using `UpdateModel(userToUpdate, new string[] {"CustomerID"}, form.ToValueProvider());` worked.